# coc-snippets doesn't complete functions

Tags: code-snippets, neovim

I'm trying to use [coc-snippets](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-snippets) for neovim, but the snippets for functions don't work as intended.

It Should be completed to: `function(param1, param2)`
But it only completes to: `function`

Here's my init.lua (minified):

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
      \ coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm() :
          \ coc#expandableOrJumpable() ? "\<C-r>=coc#rpc#request('doKeymap', ['snippets-expand-jump',''])\<CR>" :
            \ CheckBackSpace() ? "\<TAB>" :
              \ coc#refresh()

function! CheckBackSpace() abort
  let col = col('.') - 1
  return !col || getline('.')[col - 1]  =~# '\s'
endfunction
```